# corrupted file KnpSnappy

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I'm trying to use KnpSnappyBundle in my Symfony4 project. I'm actually able to translate my twig in pdf by using the command line with wkhtmltopdf but when I use KnpSnappy, the generated file is corrupted ... Here is my call in my controller :

```
 $html = $this->renderView('metier/fiche/fiche.html.twig', [
    'metier' => $this->getFirstApiResult($metierCall),
    'softskills' => $this->getSecondApiResult($skillsCall)->skills,
]);

return new PdfResponse(
    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
    'file.pdf'
);
```

Ask if you need more details.
Thanks. :)

Comment: Try opening the generated file in a text editor and see what you get.

Comment: @JonStirling i tried this before, when I open it with sublime i've got hexadecimal stuff, and on vscode i get something that looks like that :
`%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<</Title (��)
/Creator (��)`
with more lines

Comment: By corrupted, do you mean it won't open at all? Or just that the content is not right?

Comment: I mean it won't open, my pdf viewer tell me that an error occurred and the file is damaged an cannot be repared

Comment: check the file size - if its 0 bytes then it might be that the wkhtmltopdf path is not configured propertly

Comment: @katona.abel i just changed my binary to this ` /usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1280x1024x24"  /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --use-xserver`in config, and I'm able to get a pdf file without css